# Remove Truncation For Pinned Chat Messages

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-stars

Currently when you star a message in chat it appears to the right. However, if the message is more than 150 printable characters the message is truncated at that limit, and has an ellipsis appended to it.

**150 chars:**

[image]

**151+ chars:**

[image]

However, the same truncation is applied to a pinned message. A pinned message is **only** pinnable by a room owner *(or mod?)*, which typically contains important and helpful information for users.

**For example the PHP room:**

[image]

We have to resort to using abbreviations, and making the decision of omitting items *(even if useful)*, because of the truncation occurring. Can the limit be removed for pinned messages? Right now the chat message is limited to 500 chars *(excluding code blocks)* and if a message is posted that large and then pinned it should show the entire message.

Comment: Our rooms have pinned messages that are hundreds of lines long, I don't think you're acknowledging all the possible pinned messages here...and what that would look like

Comment: There is a limit (5?) on the amount of pinned messages there can be. So if you are saying it would look bad if we had a bunch of pinned messages each hundreds of chars long then you are right. But keep in mind messages can only be pinned my an owner so I would expect them to have good judgment to not pin that many long messages. Also, we are talking about printable chars, not actual chars. The PHP room example above is nearly at the 500 char limit but the printable chars is not even close to that due to the use of markup.

Comment: Correction: there can be a max of 10 starred message that can be visible at a time. All of them can be pinned as well. Any star thereafter will bump a star off the list, which can also be a pin. I still don't see it as an issue since room owners would hopefully be smart about excessive pinning, which from what I have observed has thus far been within reason.